# Hibernate collections are NULL after persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

JPA entity `Batch` has `OneToMany` relation to `Event`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "owningBatch")
private Set<Event> containingEvents;
```

and `Event` has ManyToOne relation to `Batch`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "BATCH_ID")
private Batch owningBatch;
```

after creating new instance and persisting it the `containingEvents` are still `NULL`.
But when I use empty `Set`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "owningBatch")
private Set<Event> containingEvents = Sets.newHashSet();
```

then after persisting the `containingEvents` are replaced with Hibernate's `PersistentSet`.
I would expect this replacement to happen even in first case. Why is it not happening?

DAOs are implemented by Spring Data JPA.

Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE
Spring Data JPA 2.0.4.RELEASE
Hibernate 5.2.17.Final
Hibernate JPA 2.1 1.0.2.Final

Comment: owningBatch exists in the Event class? Its annotated with @JoinColumn?

Comment: please share entities and daos.

Comment: I updated the original question with requested details.

Answer (score 1):

You need add `CascadeType` in your `@OneToMany` annotation, for example:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "owningBatch", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Event> containingEvents;
```

And you `Event` class must contain:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "batch_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Batch owningBatch;
```

Comment: @user1622058, why do you use the persist method? If you use SpringData, you only need JpaRepository.

Comment: I do use Spring Data JPA but the SimpleJpaRepository is calling entityManager.persist() under the hood. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/002640674adb7d77323237ee12336b49d7719d84/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L489